# Making a Youtbe video exclusive on my website

Tags: api, video, youtube

I have a Youtube video set to private so nobody can watch it via Youtube or the embedded player. However I do want people be to be able to watch it on my website. The goal is to make the video available exclusively on my website for a while before I open it to the world. I was thinking to login to my Youtube account seemlessly using Youtube's API and log out after the video's finished but that doesn't make security sense. What's your take on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with your intuition.  Making the private sharing secure seems tricky at best. Although the [Data API](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/getting_started.html#data_api) has procedural authentication options, I don't think [Player API](http://code.google.com/apis/youtube/getting_started.html#player_apis) has that facility.  Furthermore even if it did, it's hard to see how it might work without exposing your password.

Your best bet is probably to directly host the video on your website. You would use your website's authentication for restricting access limited release video. Then when your ready for the public release you can either switch to YouTube hosting or relax the authentication of your self hosting. The [Video for Everybody site](http://camendesign.com/code/video_for_everybody) has examples of several options for self hosting of videos.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I think self-host is the way to do in this particular case.